# How to write Typescript type for CombineReducers function when using React's useReducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is my attempt towards writinf the typescript type for `CombinedReducers` function:

```
import React, { useReducer, Reducer } from "react";

export function App() {
  return <CounterCombined />;
}

// An enum with all the types of actions to use in our reducer
enum CounterActionKind {
  INCREASE = "INCREASE",
  DECREASE = "DECREASE",
}

// An interface for our actions
interface CounterAction {
  type: CounterActionKind;
  payload: number;
}

// An interface for our state
interface CounterState {
  count: number;
}

// Our reducer function that uses a switch statement to handle our actions
const counterReducer: Reducer<CounterState, CounterAction> = (
  state: CounterState,
  action: CounterAction,
): CounterState => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log("action", action);
  switch (type) {
    case CounterActionKind.INCREASE:
      console.log("before", state);
      const updatedState = {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + payload,
      };
      console.log("updatedState", updatedState);
      console.log("after", state);
      return updatedState;
    case CounterActionKind.DECREASE:
      console.log(state);
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export interface TitleState {
  title: string;
}

export type TitleAction =
  | { type: "SET_TITLE"; payload: string }
  | { type: "CLEAR_TITLE" };

export const initialTitleState: TitleState = {
  title: "CodeSandbox",
};

export const titleReducer: Reducer<TitleState, TitleAction> = (
  state: TitleState,
  action: TitleAction,
): TitleState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_TITLE":
      return { ...state, title: action.payload };
    case "CLEAR_TITLE":
      return { ...state, title: "" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

type AppState = {
  counter: CounterState;
  title: TitleState;
};

export function combineReducers(slices: RootReducer) {
  const func = (state: AppState, action: TitleAction | CounterAction) => {
    const keysOfRootReducer: Array<keyof RootReducer> = Object.keys(
      slices,
    ) as (keyof RootReducer)[];
    const dispatch = keysOfRootReducer.reduce(
      (acc: AppState, keyOfRootReducer: keyof RootReducer) => {
        const updatedState: AppState = {
          ...acc,
          // **Below is where I am not able to fix the type.**
          [keyOfRootReducer]: slices[keyOfRootReducer](acc[keyOfRootReducer], action),
        };
        return updatedState;
      },
      state,
    );
    return dispatch;
  };
  return func;
}

type RootReducer = {
  counter: Reducer<CounterState, CounterAction>;
  title: Reducer<TitleState, TitleAction>;
};

const rootReducer: RootReducer = { counter: counterReducer, title: titleReducer };

// An example of using the `useReducer` hooks with our reducer function and an initial state

const CounterCombined = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(combineReducers(rootReducer), {
    counter: { count: 0 },
    title: { title: "sashank" },
  });
  const { counter, title } = state;
  console.log(counter, title);
  return (
    <div>
      Count: {counter.count}
      {/* Calling our actions on button click */}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: CounterActionKind.INCREASE, payload: 5 })}>
        +
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: CounterActionKind.DECREASE, payload: 5 })}>
        -
      </button>
      <h1>Hello {title.title}</h1>
      <input
        value={title.title}
        onChange={(e) => {
          dispatch({ type: "SET_TITLE", payload: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_TITLE" });
        }}
      >
        clear
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Below is the typescript playground link for a complete environment of this issue and in here the error is highlighted in red:
[Code in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KwkrvX9Ulo07oWSgioGYxGoaQq9NBmsAZ1B+WHpWkDWIPXOBjLjwW36kO354OM-B8GBSKrSEnEpMBwvdFX77vQ7f02ygbuqxbjnAANRwPNIlEnwXBgywXDNl1XdcTzPKwL2DFtoPPS992fcDqzrBsUGYE4d2DFDb30QxFEQ2DL1AocR2jd1ITaKsthnUY51Qit0LXNRd3whdCKMZln3vKtHwPMDXzlYMPzZOAAFo-wRADSCAwcQIPUgkDOfBonZITygMHjdzLLwlLECR4HxU5zjgAAVMJ9UvZk7hgfU3xgKAHFrHkjOgTV-ks6ykGoxRxk6AAfLNe0BLhRgsgB9CyugsgAZAYBBk-MUSclzpFrRhgtC-4gU4UxEqUBAYrixLOEYIQRHETzF0zBwwmAGIrIcpBLyBFqbODL0B3sxyuHMFThl1UhbAgUR5kEJTquMurNV820oBtCoRWMTq2uDbB1v8z1Jh9XRdw63zLyfJtIx81r-LjI7WtslNmU7RVIjUM6qzC-sDzQYdEk4SLSoSpKmIIpAdMUPB+MfeJfKBV7-wLSrPu+gaipK2KAc4IGuJBoiswhzaoda-KKqUhcVLUjTMcHbjFD0zoDKqsLlFUO7mU-E4E1BMjOj68L1q56aPMkMVZAjcs7AcEgVqoQh2OiYBKEIG0IAgGBFo+l8zSkWQvXY4MgRUMATtbc7tu+ELR38rR7pvOa4AAayQJJCD5ZgEGV1WpaW5QoCgBFjAdpJMkQd3Ft2uA+VsAArJAMCrAOZa0wg5YVhStGHb0A6Dt2VbVgBtABdcijzgUhgEIeEnq9eOXezj3hSoKshTofbbxetA0H15n8YDmuQ89oFM6yWu1YmVMtI1zMSKcdqmcN7rr3Hwd+PQNAFOfA4ACEkCRYJinSYJwioRIuiiDhpBVqJbH1eICmYYBRHiQ-sxXRfdFznvXb7+uoHzt9k7Sd+jte4509vnNuaBAFJGAXXSo+dsBnQ0GvRS5EsagwIKeJCwYUGMCQYJBcnFtI41LuXCkSp9JlmplrNAPJGbD09j1TobMqDLW-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-nP3yn9NG5VIWpVRHAFc5IoD6pgFWFV0Q1XwuwboBg2rBzuDRbi6Qi9nmvPeeEvJprvnkotQC5GQxUZlSSt6xefqtKytvOc1AVRnzouDZm9FUzsX7iUkAA)
Typescript error in the playground is highlighted in Red color.

Below is the line where I am getting the typescript type error

```
[keyOfRootReducer]: slices[keyOfRootReducer](acc[keyOfRootReducer], action),
```

If there is a generic way to write the typescript type for `CombinedReducers` function in React, please let me know or direct me to read a few links.

Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this will help you set up your combined reducer, but here is a code sandbox in typescript that has it all set up using the most modern method. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-setup-jof7p9

Comment: In the code-sandbox example, it is using redux's combineReducer but I am trying emulate that functionality when using React's useReducer instead of Redux slices.